# Browser Type & Version Statistics,where can i get it?

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, browser, google-chrome, version

Im Developing a website for a years, but i my bosses didn't provide me access to site statistics, so now im trying to figure out what is the popular browsers & versions of them in order to aim my website to be crossbrowser, where i can get last year/last half year browser usages if i dont own my self website?

Answer (score 1):

You can check generic sites for basic information, but what will be most helpful to you are the stats on the visitors to your particular site.  For that, you need access to the log files.

Once you have access to those logs, you can use a number of tools to process them, such as:

- [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/)
- [WebLog Expert](http://www.weblogexpert.com/)
- [Analog](http://www.analog.cx/)

I've used all three of those, and they are decent for what you need them for.  You can find a [more complete list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_analytics_software).

Answer (score 0):

[StatCounter](http://gs.statcounter.com/) will probably give you the data you need.

Comment: Not helpful for his specific site.